# problem about elements with texture in ifc format (blenderBim)

Tags: texturing

I have created a model in IFC format with BlenderBim and then I have exported it as IFC file. I use a software in order to read the IFC file but i can't see the texture of the elements. Do you know if there is a way to export IFC file with texture or if there is any software that read IFC file with texture?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: You might want to read more about this in [this thread on osarch](https://community.osarch.org/discussion/877/). Texturing in IFC is a bit complicated, and basically it boils down to the software you're opening it in to implement it how they see fit. AFAIK native IFC texture mapping is not currenly supported in the BlenderBIM addon, because there is not yet any definitive approach to how it should work according to the ifc schema.